# How do I enable NFS server on Windows 7 (Ultimate x64 in my case)?

Tags: windows-7, nfs

How do I enable NFS server on Windows 7 ?

I installed "Windows Services for UNIX" via "Turn Windows features on and off" in Control Panes. But I don't know how to launch and configure server. One hour of intensive googling didn't help me either :(

I see that there is nfsadmin.exe in System32 folder of the system. When I launch it as 'nfsadmin.exe server' it gives me error

```
Service 'NfsService' was not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you installed the Microsoft Windows Services for UNIX, the tool you install is probably to connect to a NFS server.  After Windows 2000, to have a NFS server I believe you would have to install the services for Unix on a version of Windows Server.

That said, I believe there are third party NFS servers that should work with Windows 7.  Unfortunately, I don't have any personal experience with any so I can't recommend one over another.